# Select nested array of objects inside an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

My data structure:

```
const obj = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Genre 1",
            "books": [
                { "id": 1, "name": "book 1" },
                { "id": 2, "name": "book 2" },
                { "id": 3, "name": "book 3" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Genre 2",
            "books": [
                { "id": 1, "name": "book 1" },
                { "id": 2, "name": "book 2" },
                { "id": 3, "name": "book 3" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Genre 3",
            "books": [
                { "id": 1, "name": "book 1" },
                { "id": 2, "name": "book 2" },
                { "id": 3, "name": "book 3" }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

If given an id, how can I assign the appropriate array of books to a 1
const?

Comment: You should edit your post to have valid JSON, b/c right now people are spending half of their effort on the fact that this is not valid JSON, so it would be nice to know if you go with `var <whatever> = [....]` or `var <whatever> = { "data": [...] }`. If you updated this, you could get better responses for how to find an object within an array that is the value to the key called `data` (the way I think you intended this to be, OR the object that has the correct `id` in a variable called data with an array as it's value (which some might argue would be simpler). Either way, it would help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to get to the correct object, then access the `books` array.

```
const books = data.find(d => d.id === id).books;
```

This assumes `data` is an array of objects. If you literally have an object with a key of "data", it would be closer to this:

```
const obj = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Genre 1",
      "books": [
          { "id": 1, "name": "book 1" },
          { "id": 2, "name": "book 2" },
          { "id": 3, "name": "book 3" }
       ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Genre 2",
      "books": [
          { "id": 1, "name": "book 1" },
          { "id": 2, "name": "book 2" },
          { "id": 3, "name": "book 3" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Genre 3",
      "books": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "book 1" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "book 2" },
        { "id": 3, "name": "book 3" }
      ]
  }
]};

const books = obj.data.find(d => d.id === id).books;
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

**Basic example of how to find the books with a particular ID**

```
const id_you_are_looking_for = 1;

const answer = obj.data.find(x => x.id === id_you_are_looking_for).books;
```

**You could make a function out of it...**

```
function returnBooksById(obj, id) {
    return obj.data.find(x => x.id === id).books;
}
```

**Or using arrow functions...**

```
const returnBooksById = (obj, id) => obj.data.find(x => x.id === id).books;
```

**Or, if you're using a library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#find) with ES6, it's as easy as this...**

```
import { find } from 'lodash';
const id = 1
const books = find(obj, { id }).books;
```

Comment: Avoid filter() if you are trying to find a specific entry. Filter will iterate through the entire array even after finding what you are seeking. Filter should be used when you are trying to filter one or more matching elements. Use the find() solution above by @Brandon.

Comment: You're right, for some reason I had not thought about the performance of .filter() and do agree with you now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Basic example of how to find the books with a particular ID**

```js
const result = data.books.filter(x => x.id == 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)